# How to debug C++ program in VSCode with file added

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, visual-studio-code

I work fine with debugging without adding a file, however, I do not know how to deal with it with file added.

The commands are as follows:

g++ -g --std=c++11 lab1.cpp -o lab1

./lab1 ./tests/extracredit-test-0.txt

The following are my `task.json` and `launch.json`. I wonder how to modify it to support debugging with the file added.

### launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "preLaunchTask": "build active file",
      "name": "CodeLLDB",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
    },
    {
      "preLaunchTask": "build active file",
      "name": "(lldb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb"
    },
    {
      "name": "GDB",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

      "MIMode": "gdb"

  }
  ]
}
```

### task.json

```
// Available variables which can be used inside of strings.
// ${workspaceRoot}: the root folder of the team        
// ${file}: the current opened file                     
// ${fileBasename}: the current opened file's basename 
// ${fileDirname}: the current opened file's dirname    
// ${fileExtname}: the current opened file's extension  
// ${cwd}: the current working directory of the spawned process
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build active file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++ --std=c++11 ${file} -g -o  ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "osx": {
        "command": "g++ --std=c++11 ${file} -g -o  ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
          "-ggdb",
          "\"${file}\"",
          "--std=c++11",
          "-o",
          "\"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}\""
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to debug C++ program in VSCode with file added

You are using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Consider upgrading to [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html). Then compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information) and use the [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger. You could be interested by the [static analysis facilities](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/26/static-analysis-in-gcc-10/) introduced in GCC 10, and/or by tools such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

#### Read the documentation of GCC, and of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and of your favorite debugger.

See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

If you compile a large piece of software  (e.g. a million lines of C++), you might also be interested by combining [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) or [icecream](http://linuxintro.org/wiki/Icecream) or [GCC precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)  thru your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (such as [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). In some cases, you could be interested by some C++ code generators such as [SWIG](http://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/). In some projects, you would write your own C++ code generator (e.g. with [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), [Python](https://python.org/), or [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/)). Notice that [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) uses internally *several* C++ code generators, and accepts [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

Look for inspiration inside the source code of several open source projects such as [Qt](https://qt.io/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) or [FLTK](https://fltk.org/). You could also be interested by [LinuxFromScratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, in this snippet of code

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "preLaunchTask": "build active file",
      "name": "CodeLLDB",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
    },
```

just add the file like **network.txt** in the args, in this case, that's like

```
"args": ["network.txt"]
```

and that's completed!